# How to use VBA to remove 1 (most recent) conditional formatting rule, while leaving the rest intact

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel spreadsheet with some in built conditional formatting that I don't want to touch.

I've got a macro to add a color scale (Excel calls it the "Red - Yellow - Green" color scale) to a selection, which I use simply as a diagnostic. I want to be able to quickly remove *that* rule while leaving the others intact. The macro recorder is not accomplishing this effectively.

Comment: How does it add the gradient? As cellformat in each cell?

Comment: @SvenRojek I may not have used the right words. I edited the question, now it should make sense.

Comment: are these cells affected by both rules at the same time or are they seperate on your worksheet?

Comment: @SvenRojek They are affected by both rules at the same time.

Comment: Can you give some criteria of your rule? Then you could search for that specific rule.

Comment: I don't mind adding arbitrary criteria if it would help me find it more efficiently to delete it..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60944/discussion-between-sven-rojek-and-eliyahu).

Answer (score 2):

You have to determine which Format was first. After that you can delete the FormatConditions `Item()`

```
Sub Remove_Second_Format()

    With Selection
            .FormatConditions.Item(2).Delete
    End With

End Sub
```

#### Update:

If your conditinal types are different, you could check for the type and delete all rules that equal that type. Select your cells and run this macro to remove all "xlExpression" Types

```
Sub Remove_Second_Format()

    conditions = Selection.FormatConditions.Count
    For i = 1 To conditions
        If Selection.FormatConditions(i).Type = xlExpression Then
            Selection.FormatConditions(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

There a serveral types like: `ColorScale`, `DataBar`, `xlExpression` - you must be more specific in what you really use... mind to give some code?

Comment: Here's part of it: With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).FormatColor
            .Color = 8109667 With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).FormatColor
            .Color = 7039480

Comment: In this case, just use the first solution with `.FormatConditions.Item(1).Delete` instead of `.FormatConditions.Item(2).Delete`. Or the second and change `xlExpression` with `ColorScale`

Answer (score 0):

Tried above but it got confused so it works if you delete from the last one backwards. This deletes them all:

```
For i = conditions To 1 Step -1  
 Selection.FormatConditions(i).Delete
Next i
```